# Catching bad names and out-file to txt file - need guidance

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to figure out how to capture bad computer names if they are mistyped inside the MachineName.txt file. The first script does not work but the second one does. How do I fix this? Also, the out-file only takes the computer name. I'd also like to put a date and overwrite the content in bad_names.txt every time this script is run. Thanks everyone for looking into this and appreciate the time. Also, it would be cool if I can output the message as well if the machine is offline. This is over my capability so far and I'm reaching out to the community for help. Thank you.

```
$computers = Get-Content "D:\MachineNames.txt"
    
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    If (Test-Path -Path "\\$computer\c$\Users") {
        try {
            Remove-Item -Path "\\$computer\d$\Folder1\*" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
            New-Item -Path "\\$computer\d$\" -Name Folder1 -ItemType Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
            #Transfer files...
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    
            #Start-BitsTransfer -Source "\\$env:COMPUTERNAME\d$\1.exe" -Destination "\\$computer\d$\" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose
            #Start-BitsTransfer -Source "\\$env:COMPUTERNAME\d$\Folder1\*" -Destination "\\$computer\d$\Folder1\" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose
        } 
        catch {
            "Bad name: $computer" | Out-File 'D:\bad_names.txt' -Append
        }
    }
}
```

==================================Script below works==================================

```
$computers = Get-Content "D:\MachineNames.txt"
        
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    try {
        Copy-Item -Path "\\$env:COMPUTERNAME\d$\1.exe" -Destination "\\$computer\d$\" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose
        #Copy-Item -Path "\\$env:COMPUTERNAME\d$\Folder1\*" -Destination "\\$computer\d$\Folder1\" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose
    }
    catch {
        "Bad name: $computer" | Out-File 'D:\bad_names.txt' -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the second one works as expected? `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` will cause `Copy-Item` to fail _silently_, thus never triggering the `catch` block

Comment: For odd reason it does. I get the result of the bad names in my text file.

Comment: You could use `if (Test-Connection <ComputernameFromTextFile> -Count 1 -Quiet) {..}` to test if a computer is off-line or not, but this will not tell you if the name was misspelled in the text file.. Did you create that file manually and not by using the info from Active Directory ? (tip: use `Get-ADComputer`)

Comment: I removed the if test-path statement and I get the result I needed now. But I have no knowing if the machine is offline or if the machinenames is misstyped. lol. would be nice if I can incorporate where if the test-path C:\Users from remote system is false then out-file it. I can't do IP address because it changes from time to time. Also, if I use Start-BitsTransfer the missed type names is not being out-file to the text file. But Copy-Item does. Why is this?

I want to overwrite the content inside bad_names.txt every time I run this script and would also like to include dates.

Comment: I suggest you create a machinenames.txt file with **valid** computernames simply by probing the AD and then work on the code. That way you know the names are correct and if the code fails it must be because either the machine is off-line or the file path you expect it to have is non-existent

Comment: If it's not a valid computername the script will silentycontinue but at the same time it will out-file those bad names. So far this is working using copy-item but does not work with start-bitstransfer. I prefer to use start-bitstransfer because it gives me a progress bar.

Comment: As said, get yourself an input file with correct computernames and then start thinking of whatever you want to do on those machines. Now you accept rubbish input without reason.

Answer (score 0):

In order to report whether a computer from the text file is misspelled or off-line, you need to compare each input against the correct machine names you have in your Active Directory environment.

```
# get an array of all computernames
$adComputers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter *).Name

foreach ($computer in (Get-Content -Path 'D:\MachineNames.txt'))  {
    # test if this is a valid name
    if ($adComputers -notcontains $computer) {
        "Bad name: $computer" | Add-Content -Path 'D:\bad_names.txt'
        continue   # skip this machine and proceed with the next one
    }
    # test if the machine is on line or not
    if (!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
        "Off-line: $computer" | Add-Content -Path 'D:\bad_names.txt'
        continue   # skip this machine and proceed with the next one
    }
    # try to copy the file and folder from your local machine
    $destination = "\\$computer\d$"
    if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $destination) {
        try {
            Copy-Item -Path 'D:\1.exe' -Destination $destination -Force -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose
            Copy-Item -Path 'D:\Folder1' -Destination $destination -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose
        }
        catch {
            Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }

    else {
        Write-Warning "Destination '$destination' does not exist.."
    }
}
```